# Action of a group $G$ on copies of $G$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a group and $G^n$ be the direct product of $n$ copies of $G$. There is an action $\psi$ of $G$ on the set $G^n$ such that :

$\psi\left(g,(g_1,\;g_2,\ldots,\;g_n)\right) = \left(g_1 \cdot g \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot g_1, \;g_1 \cdot g \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot g_2, \ldots, \;g_1 \cdot g \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot g_n\right)$

I'm studying this from scratch, but I'm sure this group action has already appeared somewhere. My question is therefore: has this kind of action already been studied, and if so, what was the context ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your notation. You don't seem to be acting on $n$-tuples but rather on products of $n$ elements.

Comment: Yes, that is better. It took me a while to even see that is is an action (you might want to remark that it is a right action, not a left action, since many will read action as meaning left action). I don't think I have seen this action before, though it may simply be that I have only seen it "disguised".

Comment: My answer was developed by attempting to (dis)prove that it was an action in a less tedious manner. I've run into similar formulas before (without the left/right mix) when I had my group acting too soon or too late in a more complicated situation in group cohomology.

Comment: I am curious about how you came across this action.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : I was looking for a group action on $G^n$ which respects the intervals $g_1^{-1}g_2, g_1^{-1}g_3,...,g_1^{-1}g_n$ relative to $g_1$. Of course, the basic left action sending $(g_1,...,g_n)$ to $(gg_1,...,gg_n)$ is also valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is more standard after relabeling the domain. Possibly you are dealing with more of a "projective" space, and chose the "wrong" way to make it look affine.

Consider the map $f:G^n \to G^n$ given by $f(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n) = (g_1,g_1 g_2, \dots, g_1 g_n)$.
Then $f^{-1}:G^n \to G^n$ is given by $f^{-1}(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n) = (g_1, g_1^{-1} g_2, \dots, g_1^{-1} g_n)$ and $\psi^f : G \to \operatorname{Sym}(G^n)$ is a right action given by:
$$\begin{align*}
\psi^f \left(g, \left(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n \right)\right)
&= f^{-1}\left( \psi\left( g, f\left(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\right)\right)\right) \\
&= f^{-1}\left( \psi\left( g, \left(g_1,g_1 g_2, \dots, g_1 g_n\right)\right)\right) \\
&= f^{-1}\left( g_1g, g_1g g_2, \dots, g_1g g_n \right) \\
&= \left( g_1 g, g^{-1} g_2, \dots, g^{-1} g_n \right)
\end{align*}
$$

This is more or less the standard right action on $G^n$. In the first coordinate it is right-multiplication by $g$, and on the other coordinates it is left-multiplication by $g^{-1}$. Each is standard, but I guess it is not horribly common to use both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you precise what was your context (group cohomology or other...) in which you encountered such actions ? As explained in my comment above, I was looking for an action which preserves the intervals $g_1^{-1}g_i$.

Comment: $G^n$ was $V^n$ for $V$ and abelian group and $G$ acted on $V$, but actually $G$ was supposed to act on $V^n/\Delta$ where $\Delta=\{ (v,v,\dots,v) : v \in V \}$. It was like projective space, where you can divide by any coordinate (say $g_1$) to get an equivalent "vector". As far as I recall, it was fairly close to standard ideas for extensions of groups by abelian groups. I think I had a horrible formula when I divided by $g_1$, but a good formula when I divided by $g_1^g$, which required some re-indexing all around. The "bar resolution" versus the "reduced bar resolution" might be similar.